# PHP pega dados do array SEPARAR

Tags: php

Eu recebo o valor assim `\/Date(770094000000-0300)\/` porém preciso recuperar apenas o valor *770094000000* para poder converte para data.

Comment: O tamanho dos números são sempre iguais?

Comment: sim por que ele ta pegando a data de nascimento .

Comment: então é só usar substr() pra pegar só aquela parte ali. Tu conta de onde começa e onde termina...

Answer (score 4):

Você pode usar uma ER, veja um exemplo no [**ideone**](http://ideone.com/pAbOk0).

```
$string = '/Date(770094000000-0300)/';
preg_match( "/([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)/" , $string , $match );
print_r( $match );

// output
array
(
    [0] => 770094000000-0300
    [1] => 770094000000
    [2] => 0300
)
```

Answer (score 4):

Solução simples para **numeração fixa** (o número sempre terá o mesmo tamanho).

```
$minha_string = '/Date(770094000000-0300)/';

$numero_desejado = substr($minha_string, 6, 12);

echo $numero_desejado; // irá exibir 770094000000
```

Solução utilizando Expressões Regulares.

```
$minha_string = '/Date(770094000000-0300)/';

preg_match('/\((\d+)/', $minha_string, $numero_desejado );

echo $numero_desejado[1]; // irá exibir 770094000000
```

Comment: Isso que eu falei ali em cima.

Comment: @ZebraDoMal verdade, disse mesmo :-)

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a função **[preg_match](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match.php)** e obter os valores usando uma expressão regular:

**[Demo Ideone](https://ideone.com/tTRth2)**

```
$str = '/Date(770094000000-0300)/';
preg_match( '/\d+\-\d+/', $str, $match );
var_dump( $match );
```